# How to publish an array of strings?

Tags: ros, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

operation=['addition','subtraction','multiplication','division']

I want to publish each element in the array from one node and subscribe those elements by other node. What should be the proper python syntax for publishing and subscribing ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249340/how-to-publish-an-array-of-strings?/) by [mhharshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/28703/mhharshal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Read The Friendly Manual: [Publishers and Subscribers](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mhharshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/28703/mhharshal/) on 2016-12-04**:
I was able to publish simple data such as integers, but when I tried for arrays, ros was giving some error. How can we publish it properly?

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-12-04**:
" ros was giving some error. "  It would be easier if you'd tell exactly(!) which error is returned. And do you want to publish an array or "each element in the array"?